# Lyx template for scientific paper

Tags: templates, lyx

Anyone know of any simple Template for scientific paper which is easy to modify and looks great? So that i don't have to use several hour to find out the syntax.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the "article" document class with two columns. If you use sections, author, title and abstract (from the drop down menu), you should get something that "looks" like a scientific paper without any need for templates or coding. However, the layout will be more basic than if you try something like was suggested by Reinderien, which is feasible (as Lyx does indeed use TeX).

Answer (score 1):

LyX includes the template file `elsarticle.lyx`, a template for Elsevier journal articles based on the [`elsarticle` class.](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/authorsview.authors/elsarticle)

Answer (score 0):

The IEEE has a good one: http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/authors_journals.html#sect2

Comment: LYX Does not support .Tex. I need template for Lyx

Answer (score 0):

"CLASSICTHESIS" by André Miede is pretty good for scientific papers

Quote from the [authors website](http://www.miede.de/index.php?page=classicthesis):

> The main goals of the template are:
>
> 1. Providing students with an easy-to-use template for their Master's or PhD thesis. (Though it might also be used by other types of authors for reports, books, etc.)
> 2. Providing authors with a classic, high quality typographic style which is inspired by Robert Bringhurst's "The Elements of Typographic Style".

You can download the template [here](http://code.google.com/p/classicthesis/)