# How can I become proficient in LaTeX?

Tags: learning

I read three books about LaTeX, but I am still a beginner, I can't use `tikz`, `tcbset`, `tcolorbox`, `newcommand`, `tikzpicture` .. environments, I just copy and paste.

What should I read after these books?

1. [LaTeX Beginner's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847199860)
2. [LaTeX Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1784395145)
3. [LaTeX in 24 Hours: A Practical Guide for Scientific Writing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319478303)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539802/how-to-get-better-at-latex

Comment: Hi and welcome. The best way to progress is to practice. This forum is the ideal place for that. Try to respond to the problems posed by others. Then compare your solution with that of others. You learn by practicing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Wow, 110.73$ in books!! Stefan is a master and absolutely recommendable, but I have not found the other author on TeX.SE. Have you tried the "Not So Short Intro..." by Tobias Oetiker? https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf. It is a very good introduction and it is free. Then, for Tikz, read the manual http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf. Ok, 1318 pages is tough, but it is worth the effort. And it is free also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX!

I would recommend to make a free account at Overleaf (https://www.overleaf.com/) and start practicing. Overleaf is easy to use for beginners, and it has a great tutorial. For example, as you mentioned `TikZ`, here is a good link:
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TikZ_package

Start running examples and play by changing the code to develop an understanding of the implementation. Feel free to post a new question when you get stuck on a specific problem. This community is very helpful.

Another resource I would recommend is https://texample.net/. It has a lot of examples that you can just paste in Overleaf, run and play around to develop intuition and gain expertise. For `TikZ`, see https://texample.net/tikz/examples/

Best of luck!

Answer (score 6):

Don't just read. Start writing and then google whatever you need.

It's unlikely that there will be a problem that hasn't been already been addressed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!