# Building a specific flow chart diagram

Tags: flow-charts

Reference links for tutorials on how to build flowchart diagrams

Comment: You could use the link below: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoBC8zIB-3k Real sorry for my audacity, but I don't have much time on hand and I saw your question...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some good tutorials/starting points:

1. [Overleaf TikZ](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ:_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_3)%E2%80%94Creating_Flowcharts)
2. [texample](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/)

See my comment [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557584/how-can-i-become-proficient-in-latex) for details